# More concise way to use without_access_control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, declarative-authorization

I'm working on an app that uses declarative_authorization for model security and there are allot of tests where I'm constructing fixtures and don't want/need them to go through the authorization framework.  Currently I'm using something like the code snippet below but since this is going to be a fairly common task I was wondering if there was a better or more concise way to accomplish the same goal.

```
def disable_auth(code, *args)
  without_access_control do
    return code.call(*args)
  end
end

get :index, :product_id => disable_auth( lambda { Factory(:product) } )
```

Comment: If this is Ruby on Rails, you should probably put the `ruby-on-rails` tag in your question, too. (I'm not sure if it is or not, or I'd edit it for you.)

Comment: This is ruby on rails but I figured It was applicable to ruby in general.

Answer (score 0):

I usually sign in as an authorized user in the begin block of my tests. This makes it easy to write tests that verify that my permissions are working the way I want them to.

I wouldn't do it the way you describe.

Comment: In this particular instance I'm verifying that an anonymous user can't access a pre-existing product.  I have lots of tests similar to this that require some pre-existing state which is then accessed by users of various other permission levels.  Signing in with multiple users to create a fixture then switching users to do the actual test is a PITA.